# Evaluate $\iint_{R}(x^2+y^2)dxdy$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, proof-verification

$$\iint_{R}(x^2+y^2)dxdy$$

> $$0\leq r\leq 2 \,\, ,\frac{\pi}{4}\leq \theta\leq\frac{3\pi}{4}$$

**My attempt :**

Jacobian=r

$$=\iint_{R}(x^2+y^2)dxdy$$

$$x:=r\cos \theta \,\,\,,y:=r\cos \theta$$

$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=r$$

$$\int_{\theta=\pi/4}^{\theta=3\pi/4}\bigg[\int_{r=0}^{r=2}\bigg(r^2\bigg)dr\bigg]d\theta$$

$$.....=\boxed{\frac{4\pi}{3}}$$

> Is it correct?

[image]>

Comment: Why did you mention the Jacobian if you left it out?

Comment: Did you forget to include the Jacobian?

Comment: Without the jacobian is only $r$, no?, this is the reason that it is $r\times J=r^2$

Comment: $x^2+y^2=r^2{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply Jacobian in integrand

$$\int_{\theta=\pi/4}^{\theta=3\pi/4}\bigg[\int_{r=0}^{r=2}\bigg(r^3\bigg)dr\bigg]d\theta$$

Answer (score 1):

Switching to polar coordinates, the Jacobian is given by $ |J|$ where $$ J = \dfrac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(r,\theta)} = \begin{vmatrix} \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial r} & \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial r} \\ \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial \theta} & \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial \theta} \end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix} \cos\theta & \sin\theta \\ -r\sin\theta & r\cos\theta \end{vmatrix} = r$$ Therefore, your double integral is given by $$ \begin{aligned} \iint_{R} \left( x^2 + y^2 \right) \text{ d}x \text{ d}y & = \int_{\pi/4}^{3\pi/4} \int_{0}^{2} \left( (r\cos\theta)^2 + (r\sin\theta)^2 \right) |J| \text{ d}r \text{ d}\theta \\ & = \int_{\pi/4}^{3\pi/4} \int_{0}^{2} r^2 |r| \text{ d}r \text{ d}\theta \end{aligned}$$ and since $r \in \left[0,2\right]$, $|r| = +r$ so the integrand is $r^3$. I leave the rest to you.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @tired!

Answer (score -1):

while converting in polar co-ordinate you have directly taken dx*dx=dr*d(theta),
you have to use polar transformation Jacobin to do so, that is dx*dx=r*dr*d(theta), then integrate normally

answer will be (ip/2).

Comment: The answer is $2\pi$